# FluorineFX and WCF

Tags: wcf, fluorinefx

andHi,

I have been asking the same question in a lot of forums, including the Fluorine FX and nobody asnwered me.

I am a user of FluorineFx with Flex/AIR and I have a huge legacy in WCF Services. I need to develop an application and I would like to use Flex/AIR. The problem is how can I call my WCF services from Flex/AIR using FluorineFX.

The source code of Fluorine include a specific project called Fluorine.WCF, but there is no documentation.

How can I use it ???

FluorineFX is a very good project and I have a lot of applications using this framework. The support was allways good and I could solve all my problems. But now, I do not know why, I cannot receive any answer. Is there anything wrong with FluorineFX ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you use FluorineFX to call your WCF Services? We use the AS3 class HTTPService to call our REST WCF Services. Calling SOAP WCF Services on the other hand is not easy. For both REST and SOAP calls, the wizards in Flex to generate code don't seem very thrust full.

If you want an open api, I suggest using REST (Xml or Json. Can be configured in your WCF Services). You can use WebGet or WebInvoke.

If you really want to use FluorineFX to call a WCF service, take a look at [this](http://old.nabble.com/attachment/30886924/0/CalculatorService.zip) example by Zoli himself. You'll probably need the latest version of FluorineFX from [SVN](http://code.google.com/p/fluorinefx/source/checkout).

I do think using FluorineFX to call WCF Services is kind off overhead, but I could be wrong.